# Applying apply_joint_effort and apply_body_wrench

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi again.

I'm simulating in Gazebo the R2D2 robot from [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials/Adding%20Physical%20and%20Collision%20Properties%20to%20a%20URDF%20Model) tutorial (although there is no link in this page, I dowloaded all the urdf tutorials stacks and there is a model called 07-physics.urdf with the correct physics of the robot).

I'm trying to apply some forces to the joints to interact with the robot using [/apply_joint_effort and /apply_body_wrench](http://www.ros.org/wiki/gazebo).

First, I spawn the robot:

```
rosrun gazebo spawn_model -urdf -file 07-physics.urdf -model r2d2 -z 0.5
```

Next, I make a shell script that executes the next orders:

```
rosservice call /gazebo/apply_joint_effort '{joint_name: "left_back_wheel_joint", effort: -0.2, start_time: 0, duration: -1 }'
rosservice call /gazebo/apply_joint_effort '{joint_name: "left_front_wheel_joint", effort: -0.2, start_time: 0, duration: -1 }'
```

I obtained the following possible answers:

- The robot turns a little to the right
  before hitting the ground and go
  straight. (Most common).
- The robot is rotating to the
  right while moving in a "straight"
  direction.
- The robot dumps (also quite common
  xD).

I tried to change the start time (setting to 5, 10...) and the duration (setting to 50000, 500, 50...), but the response is always the same. I think that the **correct answer would be** that the robot will rotate on itself pivoting on the imaginary axis of the right wheels.

What I doing bad? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9437/applying-apply_joint_effort-and-apply_body_wrench/) by [mbj](https://answers.ros.org/users/265/mbj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 197 on 2011-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer wasn't the correct because I didn't apply a correct contact propierties of the wheel (friction coefficients, contact stiffnes and contact damping, explained [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials/UnderstandingPR2URDFGazeboExtension) and [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/XML/Gazebo)). When this was solved, the answer was the expected.

Although this, I only obtain correct responses when the duration time was -1 (infinite). When I set the duration_time or start_time to any positive valor (like 50) Gazebo worked as if it had been set to infinity.

---

Originally posted by [mbj](https://answers.ros.org/users/265/mbj/) with karma: 197 on 2011-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0